# Is -[NSView setsNeedsDisplay:] a synchronous call?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have an `NSView` in a Mac OS X application that draws itself.  When I am ready for this to happen I request it with the call:

```
[self.imageRenderedView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

My question is, does this call block? That is, is it synchronous, and can I assume the drawing has happened by the time the subsequent statement is executed? This assumption seems to work for me, but I feel a bit insecure about it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `setNeedsDisplay:` call only *marks* the view as needing display by setting
a flag in the view object.
Therefore it returns very quickly, but the drawing has *not* yet happened when the method returns.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplay%3a):

> Whenever the data or state used for drawing a view object changes, the
>   view should be sent a `setNeedsDisplay:` message. `NSView` objects marked
>   as needing display are automatically redisplayed on each pass through
>   the application’s event loop. (View objects that need to redisplay
>   before the event loop comes around can of course immediately be sent
>   the appropriate `display...` method.)

Comment: Thanks, so if I use:    [self.imageRenderedView display]; that solves my problem and it is twelve characters less to type. I don't think the process takes a significant time.

Comment: @DavidElliman: From the "View Programming Guide:": In general, you should avoid calling the display family of methods to redraw your views. If you must call them, do so infrequently. Because they cause an immediate call to your drawRect: routine, they can cause performance to slow down significantly by preempting other pending operations. They also preclude the ability to coalesce other changes and then redraw those changes all at once.

Comment: @DavidElliman Or, to be blunt, `setNeedsDisplay` and `display` don't, at all, do the same thing.   You should never call `display` and you should never assume that drawing will happen as the result of calling `setNeedsDisplay`.

Comment: I am grabbing the pixels of the displayed image and doing some image processing on them. In fact I am using them to train a pattern recognition system. This is a very unusual situation.  So I do need the View to have finished drawing before I do that.  So display works fine. Of course, this is not something to do in a normal user interface. If cocoa gave a viewDidFinishDrawing callback hat would be better, but they don't seem to do that.

Comment: @DavidElliman: If you're subclassing `NSView`, then you know it's done drawing at the end of `drawRect:`